# UITableViewController: cellForRowAtIndexPath keeps looping through section 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 5 sections.  After going through section 0, I'm not sure why cellForRowAtIndex keeps looping through Section 1.  Below is the code and log.  Thanks

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    numberOfSections = 0;

    if ([pastSevenDayArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;

    NSLog (@"numberofSections %i", numberOfSections);

    [self numberOfCells];

    return numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return sectionZeroCellCount;
    }

    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return sectionOneCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        return sectionTwoCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 3)
    {
        return sectionThreeCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 4)
    {
        return sectionFourCellCount;
    }
    if (section == 5)
    {
        return sectionFiveCellCount;
    }
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"IndexPath Section %i", [indexPath section]);


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 0");

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 1");
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 2");
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 3");
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 4)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 4");

    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 5)
    {
        NSLog(@"Entered Section 5");
    }

    NSString *entityName = [[object entity]name];
    //NSString *userName= [object valueForKey:@"recipientUserName"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %i", entityName, [indexPath row]];
    NSDate *date = [object valueForKey:@"lastmoddate"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, YYYY  h:mm a"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;
    object = NULL;

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

numberOfCells

```
-(void)numberOfCells
{
    for (int section = 0; section<numberOfSections; section ++)
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            if ([pastSevenDayArray count] > 0)
            {
                SevenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastSevenDayArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = sevenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                fourteenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastFourteenDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = fourteenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;

            }
            else if ([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastArray count] > 0)
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

        else if (section == 1)
        {    
            if (([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0) && (fourteenDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                fourteenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastFourteenDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = fourteenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (thirtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==2)
        {
            if (([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (thirtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==3)

        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;          
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==4)
        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFourCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionFourHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFourCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionFourHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

        else if (section ==5)
        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFiveCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionFiveHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return sectionZeroCellCount;
    }

    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return sectionOneCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        return sectionTwoCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 3)
    {
        return sectionThreeCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 4)
    {
        return sectionFourCellCount;
    }
    if (section == 5)
    {
        return sectionFiveCellCount;
    }
}
```

Log

```
2013-08-14 18:06:16.222 Time[5241:c07] numberofSections 5
2013-08-14 18:06:16.226 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 0
2013-08-14 18:06:16.227 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 0
2013-08-14 18:06:16.228 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.229 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.229 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.229 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.230 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.230 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.230 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.231 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.231 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.232 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.232 Time[5241:c07] IndexPath Section 1
2013-08-14 18:06:16.232 Time[5241:c07] Entered Section 1
```

Comment: What does [self numberOfCells] do? Can you post the code?

Comment: What are your values for sectionZeroCellCount, etc? If sectionTwoCellCount and on are 0, you won't ever have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called for those sections.

Comment: I just updated it with Edit.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1107173  how many rows did you expect in section 1 when you got that log?

Comment: My reason for asking is that cellForRow is called at least once per visible row per section. This is exactly the log I'd expect to see when starting up a fresh table and seeing the first 7 rows populated. If I'm incorrect in that hunch, then what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: Sorry Carl.  You're right.  The Log is correct.  I wasn't scrolling!  I'm embarrassed!

Comment: @user1107173 It's OK, don't feel embarrassed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called once per visible row per section. This log is indicative of a table view becoming visible with one row in section 0 and at least six rows in section 1. If you scroll it further, you may see additional sections logged as the rows for them become visible. So, this log is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you change:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

It will work, unless you think you need to specify the indexPath of the cell as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in numberOfCells.

You are doing a lot of pointer comparisons with NSNumbers like this:

```
pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

That is NOT going to work as you are comparing the POINTERS of those NSNumber instances. if you want to test if pastArraySectioned is true, you simply need to get its bool value like this:

```
[pastArraySectioned boolValue]
```